# TypeScript error TS1005: ',' expected Nada me resulta!

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Tengo el siguiente problema, al compilar mi código me lanza el siguiente error:

> ERROR in src/app
>   /components/login/login.component.ts(9,2): error TS1005: ',' expected.

He visto varios post y he hecho lo que dicen pero nada funciona.

- Versión de "typescript": "^2.7.2".
- Versión de "tsc": "^2.9.2".

Espero su ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html'
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
 providers: [UserService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
 public title:string;
 public user:User;
 public status: string;
 public identity;
 public token;

 constructor(
 private _route: ActivatedRoute,
 private _router: Router,
 private _userService: UserService
 ){
  this.title = 'Acceder';
  this.user = new User("","","","","","","ROLE_ADMIN","");
 }


 ngOnInit(){
 console.log('Cargado');
 }

 onSubmit(){

 //Loguear al usuario y conseguir sus datos

 this._userService.signup(this.user).subscribe(
  response => {
   this.identity = response.user;
   if(!this.identity || !this.identity._id){
   this.status = 'error';
   }else{

   //Persistir datos del usuario
   localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));


   this.getToken();
   }
   
  },
  error => {

   var errorMessage = <any>error;
   console.log(errorMessage);

   if(errorMessage != null){
    this.status = 'error';
   }
  }

 );
 }

 getToken(){

 this._userService.signup(this.user, 'true').subscribe(
  response => {
   this.token = response.token;
   if(this.token.length <= 0){
   this.status = 'error';
   }else{

   //Persistir token del usuario

   localStorage.setItem('token',this.token);

   //Conseguir contadores o estadisticas del usuario
   
   this.getCounters();

   }
   
  },
  error => {

   var errorMessage = <any>error;
   console.log(errorMessage);

   if(errorMessage != null){
    this.status = 'error';
   }
  }

 );
 
}

getCounters(){
 
 this._userService.getCounters().subscribe(
 response => {
 localStorage.setItem('stats', JSON.stringify(response));

 this.status = 'success';
 this._router.navigate(['/']);
 },
 error =>{

 console.log(<any>error);
 }

 );
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Te falta una

> **,**

en `templateUrl: './login.component.html'`

Debería quedar asi:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [UserService]
})
```

Pero si no me equivoco tienes algún error de sintaxis mas

Comment: Gracias!! Si me faltaba esa coma y no me di cuenta. Jeje